# How to get number of lines of code of a file in a remote repo using PyGithub/ Githubsearch api?

Tags: github-pages, github-api, gitpython, pygithub

```
commit = repo.get_commit(sha="0adf369fda5c2d4231881d66e3bc0bd12fb86c9a")
print(commit.stats.total)
i = commit.files[0].filename
```

I can get the filename, even the file sha; but can't seem to get loc of the file. Any pointers?

Comment: When you say lines of code, do you mean including documentation (e.g., docstrings) or only executable lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's see this line

```
commit = repo.get_commit(sha="0adf369fda5c2d4231881d66e3bc0bd12fb86c9a")
```

Here the `commit` is of type [github.Commit.Commit](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Commit.html#github.Commit.Commit)

Now when you pick a file, it's of the type [github.File.File](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/File.html#github.File.File)

If you checked that, you'll see that there is no real way of getting lines of code directly. But there is one important field `raw_url`.

This will give you the `raw_url` of the file, which you can now get, perhaps like

```
url = commit.files[0].raw_url
r = requests.get(url)
r.text
```

This will give you the raw data of the file and you can use it to get the number of lines of code.